# Can 2 Miis of the same gender be sweethearts/married in Tomodachi Life?

Tags: tomodachi-life

Can 2 Miis of the same gender be sweethearts/married?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is no. Same-gender relationships are not a thing in Tomodachi Life. A fact that stirred up some controversy once it came to light.

There *is* an imperfect workaround to this limitation, however. Because the Mii Maker will allow you to put any hairstyle, voice, facial features, or personality onto a Mii regardless of their gender; you can for example, give a male Mii a female name and look, and they can hook up with other females. Thus, the same thing goes for the males.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. This isn't possible. [This article explains a little bit more about Nintendo's stance, but at the core, the answer is no.](http://www.cbc.ca/news/nintendo-s-tomodachi-life-won-t-allow-for-gay-avatars-1.2634725)

Answer (score 1):

No. Miis with the same gender can't get married or be sweethearts. However you can create a Mii that has the opposite gender look and voice and have them become sweethearts that makes it look like they're both the same gender!

[More here](http://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-have-same-sex-relationships-in-tomodachi-life/)

Comment: How does this differ from [Trent’s answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/178205/181240)?